# caching image and load them

Tags: android, caching, image-processing, image-gallery

I downloaded images and cached them into my cache folder by using Fedora's lazylist but now, instead of displaying them into a listview. I need to make use of a viewpager + touchimageview. I have already found the example but have no idea how to load them into the AndroidTouchGallery. Can someone give me pointers?

This is the filecache.java

```
package com.fedorvlasov.lazylist;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

import android.content.Context;

public class FileCache {

    private File cacheDir;

    public FileCache(Context context){
        //Find the dir to save cached images
        if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
            cacheDir=new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"LazyList");
        else
            cacheDir=context.getCacheDir();
        if(!cacheDir.exists())
            cacheDir.mkdirs();
    }

    public File getFile(String url){
        //I identify images by hashcode. Not a perfect solution, good for the demo.
        //String filename=String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
        //Another possible solution (thanks to grantland)
        String filename = URLEncoder.encode(url);
        File f = new File(cacheDir, filename);
        return f;

    }

    public void clear(){
        File[] files=cacheDir.listFiles();
        if(files==null)
            return;
        for(File f:files)
            f.delete();
    }

}
```

the memory cache (also by fedora)

```
package com.fedorvlasov.lazylist;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.util.Log;

public class MemoryCache {

    private static final String TAG = "MemoryCache";
    private Map<String, Bitmap> cache=Collections.synchronizedMap(
            new LinkedHashMap<String, Bitmap>(10,1.5f,true));//Last argument true for LRU ordering
    private long size=0;//current allocated size
    private long limit=1000000;//max memory in bytes

    public MemoryCache(){
        //use 25% of available heap size
        setLimit(Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()/4);
    }

    public void setLimit(long new_limit){
        limit=new_limit;
        Log.i(TAG, "MemoryCache will use up to "+limit/1024./1024.+"MB");
    }

    public Bitmap get(String id){
        try{
            if(!cache.containsKey(id))
                return null;
            //NullPointerException sometimes happen here http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/issues/detail?id=78 
            return cache.get(id);
        }catch(NullPointerException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void put(String id, Bitmap bitmap){
        try{
            if(cache.containsKey(id))
                size-=getSizeInBytes(cache.get(id));
            cache.put(id, bitmap);
            size+=getSizeInBytes(bitmap);
            checkSize();
        }catch(Throwable th){
            th.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void checkSize() {
        Log.i(TAG, "cache size="+size+" length="+cache.size());
        if(size>limit){
            Iterator<Entry<String, Bitmap>> iter=cache.entrySet().iterator();//least recently accessed item will be the first one iterated  
            while(iter.hasNext()){
                Entry<String, Bitmap> entry=iter.next();
                size-=getSizeInBytes(entry.getValue());
                iter.remove();
                if(size<=limit)
                    break;
            }
            Log.i(TAG, "Clean cache. New size "+cache.size());
        }
    }

    public void clear() {
        try{
            //NullPointerException sometimes happen here http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/issues/detail?id=78 
            cache.clear();
            size=0;
        }catch(NullPointerException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    long getSizeInBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if(bitmap==null)
            return 0;
        return bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight();
    }
}
```

this is the part where i am supposed to load the cached data into the touchgallery. Previously I just needed to load in an array of strings (data was stored in the sdcard), now how do i display the items I downloaded as cache over at touchgallery?

```
public class UrlTouchImageView extends RelativeLayout {
    protected ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    protected TouchImageView mImageView;

    protected Context mContext;
    UrlPagerAdapter pagerAdapter;
    String[] mImageIds;
    Bitmap bm;
    ArrayList<String>  mStringList= new ArrayList<String>();


    public UrlTouchImageView(Context ctx, UrlPagerAdapter pagerAdapter)
    {
        super(ctx);
        mContext = ctx;
        this.pagerAdapter = pagerAdapter;

        init();

    }
    public UrlTouchImageView(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(ctx, attrs);
        mContext = ctx;
        init();
    }

    public TouchImageView getImageView() 
    { 
        return mImageView; 
    }


    protected void init() {

        mImageView = new TouchImageView(mContext);
        LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        mImageView.setLayoutParams(params);
        this.addView(mImageView);
        mImageView.setVisibility(GONE);


        mProgressBar = new ProgressBar(mContext, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleHorizontal);
        params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        params.setMargins(30, 0, 30, 0);
        mProgressBar.setLayoutParams(params);
        mProgressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
        this.addView(mProgressBar);
    }

    public void setUrl(String imageUrl)
    {
        new ImageLoadTask().execute(imageUrl);
    }

    //No caching load
    public class ImageLoadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Bitmap>
    {
        //RETRIEVES LINK FROM GALLERYACTIVITY
        //READ MNT/SDCARD/....

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... strings) {
            bm = null;
            String url = strings[0];
            //Log.d("url",url);

            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(url);
            return bm;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {

            mImageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
            mImageView.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(GONE);
        }
    }
}
```

I am sorry for my bad english as well as poor knowledge to android programming. hopefully you all can give me advices..

Comment: here you can explore example of [loading images asynchronously](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-asynchronous-image-loading-in-listview/)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use this library.

https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-BitmapCache